# How to ignore exports when going to definitions in vscode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Consider this plain example:

```
//a.js
function world() { console.log("World world world"); }

module.exports = { world };
```

```
//b.js
const a = require('./a');
a.world();
```

When I ctrl+click / use the "Go to Definitions" command on `world` from file b, I'm told there are 2 definitions for `world` and I need to pick the one I wish to jump to. But one of those is the `module.exports` statement which really isn't interesting or useful at all to me.

Is there a way to ignore the `module.exports` definition of any/all symbols? So that "Go to definition" will go to the *real* definition automatically?

[image]

Comment: Eventually while converting typescript and es6 modules, I switched to `export function world(){}` syntax. The problem went away, but that isn't a solution.